# Putting else statement in a loop

Tags: python, function

All I want to do is add an else statement at the end e.g else: print('Incorrect') but I keep getting an error saying unexpected indent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), 
              ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]
    
def average_age(members,gender):
    ages = []
    for g in members:
        if g[2] == gender:
            ages.append(g[1])
    return sum(ages) / len(ages)
        else:
            print('No matches found.')
    
average_age(people, 'M')
```

```
 File "<ipython-input-95-47432c006dc9>", line 7
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] of the code that gives the error mentioned. Otherwise, we can only tell you that you must indeed "just" put an else at the end. Did you properly align the `else` with either `if` or `for`?

Comment: The IDE must be showing line number of the error. Check that line and u will get it

Comment: I have edited the above code to show you exactly what error I am seeing when I try to add an else

Comment: upvoted or adding test data and improving answer following comments

Comment: The code you're actually running doesn't have the indentation of the code you've posted, because the code you've posted would give an indentation error in line 2. If your question involves indentation problems it is very unhelpful to post code with different indentation problems from your real code.

Comment: @khelwood: Sorry, I guessed at some of the indentation. I'm sure that this is what the OP has though.

Comment: You can't have anything else in a function after a `return` at that indentation. Anyway what does it mean to your clients if they expect a number back, but receive a `None` instead?

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I am new to using functions and did not realise you cannot have an else after a return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You cant use `else` without an `if`)
and there cant be anyting after a  `return`

You can check the length of `ages` before returning

`if` something is in there `return`

`else` you can `print` something

```py
def average_age(members,gender):
    ages = []
    for g in members:
        if g[2] == gender:
            ages.append(g[1])
    if len(ages) > 0:
        return sum(ages) / len(ages)
    else:
        print('No matches found.')

average_age(people, 'M')
```

Comment: You *can* use an `else:` without an `if`. It just has to be with a `while` or `for`.

Comment: @quamrana or a try...except...else

Comment: well thats right, it can also be after `try` - but in this case he needs the `if`

Comment: @Guddi: No, I think the OP means to have an `else:` that follows the `for`.

Comment: @mdmjsh: Yes, try as well. Have we missed anything?

Comment: Thank you so much for this!, I never thought of  if len(ages) > 0:
        return sum(ages) / len(ages)

Answer (score 1):

In python, [indentation is part of the syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) - e.g. the number of spaces matter. If the interpreter is giving an indentation error means you've not correctly indented your code. This works:

```
def average_age(members,gender):
    ages = []
    for g in members:
        if g[2] == gender:
            ages.append(g[1])
        else:
            print('Incorrect')
    return sum(ages) / len(ages)
```

```
In [6]: average_age(people, 'M')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Incorrect
Incorrect
Incorrect
Out[6]: 26.5
```

Edit: Since I posted this the OP edited the question to include the return statement - This issue here is actually that you're calling `else` after the `return` statement on this line:

```
return sum(ages) / len(ages)
    else:
        print('No matches found.')
```

This is invalid syntax. The If/Else need to appear in the same logical flow of the program (the `else` here is unreachable code as the function would have already returned). If you're new to python, I highly  recommend you check out real python for some good tutorials, such as this one on [conditional statements.](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/)

Answer (score 1):

From indentation perspective it should be like this:

```
def average_age(members,gender):
    ages = []
    for g in members:
        if g[2] == gender:
            ages.append(g[1])
            break   # leave loop once if matches gender
    else:
        print('no break hit')
    return sum(ages) / len(ages)
```

In for loop else typically works with break, else clause runs when no break occurs, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html. You can try refactoring like this:

```
import statistics
def average_age(people,gender):
    return statistics.mean((i[1] for i in people if i[2] == gender))
```

shorter is better

Comment: i dont think this helps, he want to get the average age, so it needs more than one member xD

Comment: Thank you for your help Jacek - this is almost what I need, If i edit out the break. I am looking for an output of just 26.5 but with this i currently get output: No matches found.
26.5

Comment: import statistics module then calculate average age with 
statistics.mean((i[1] for i in people if i[2] == gender))
see edited function